# Create KML from MXD that contains map service layers like feature layers

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, arcpy

How can I create a KML (tools suggestion), provided that I have a map (.mxd) file which layers are service layers of hosted services and not local data coming from a geodatabase.
I know that the map to kml tool works only for local data and not with data coming from services.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Since ArcGIS Server 10.1, the ability to include a hosted service inside a map service has been disabled.

You should get the following error if you try to publish an mxd containing one:
[ArcGIS for Server error description](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00sq0000001m000000)

Perhaps you could scrape the data from the hosted service and recreate the service.